# Take $k$ shoes ($k \leqslant n$) from a wardrobe. What is the expected value of the number of pairs ($X$) you take?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm having trouble with this question:

Let there be $2n$ shoes ($n$ pairs) in a wardrobe, arbitrary ordened. Take $k$ shoes ($k \leqslant n$) from that wardrobe. What is the expected value of the number of pairs ($X$) you take?

I know that the answer is $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{n{2n - 2 \choose k - 2}}{2n \choose k}$, but I don't understand why. Could you explain this to me? I think I have to split the random variable $X$ into some smaller $X_i 's$, which have an easier expected value to compute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neevr mind I had a comment but I read your OP again and it was cleared up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable for the event that the $i$th pair is picked (i.e. $X_i$ is $1$ if pair $i$ is picked and $0$ if it isn't picked).  Then $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$.  Since expectation is linear, we also have $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X_1) + \ldots + \mathbb{E}(X_n)$, so we need only find $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$.  We have $$ \mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mathbb{P}(i\text{th pair is chosen}) = \frac{\binom{2n - 2}{k - 2}}{\binom{2n}{k}}$$
since there are $\binom{2n - 2}{k - 2}$ ways to choose $k$ elements from $2n$ if we require that the $i$th pair is chosen, and there are a total of $\binom{2n}{k}$ ways to choose.  Thus, we have $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum \mathbb{E}(X_i) = n \frac{\binom{2n - 2}{k - 2}}{\binom{2n}{k}}. $$

Comment: After simplifying one obtains ${\mathbb E}(X)={1\over 2n-1}{k\choose 2}$. Maybe there is an intuitive explanation for this result.

Comment: @Marcus M Thanks! very helpful! The only thing I don't see is where the $2n - 2 \choose k - 2$ comes from. If I take $2n = 6$ and $k = 3$, then there are 6 ways to chose 3 shoes from 6 if a certain pair has to be chosen, and not $4 \choose 1$ as it should be in the formula you stated above

Comment: @Peter To choose $k$ of $2n$ shoes including the $i$-the pair you must also choose $k-2$ of the remaining $2n-2$ shoes.  Thus the probability is $\color{silver}{\binom{2}{2}} \binom{2n-2}{k-2} \big/ \binom{2n}{k}$.

Comment: To choose 3 of 6 shoes containing particular pair you must also choose 1 of the remaining 4 shoes.  That is indeed $\binom 4 1 \big/ \binom 6 3$

Answer (score 2):

Christian Blatter commented that $E(X)$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{k}{2}$, and suggested there might be an intuitive explanation.

Suppose that we have chosen $k$ shoes and lined them up in a row. Let $t=\binom{k}{2}$ be the number of $2$-shoe subsets.  For $i=1$ to $t$, let $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th subset is a matching pair, and let $Y_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number of matching pairs $X$ is given by $X=Y_1+\cdots+Y_t$. By the linearity of expectation we have $E(X)=E(Y_1)+\cdots +E(Y_t)$.

For any $2$-shoe subset, the probability the second matches the first is $\frac{1}{2n-1}$. Thus $E(Y_i)=\frac{1}{2n-1}$ and the expected number of matching pairs is $\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{k}{2}$.